# How to read a char array from a binary file in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, binaryfiles, binary-data

Before you ask me if I have searched information before making this post (because I know you are going to ask it), yes, I did.

I'm doing a program where I load data after having saved them in a binary file. I have problems when I try to read the data from the binary file, and after being looking for hours what fails, I still do not know what is.

First, I store the information in the binary file:

```
ofstream of;

of << s.num;
of << s.array;
```

Where num is an int and array is a char array[kARRAY]

And then I try to read it this way:

```
ifstream fi;

int auxNum;
char auxArray[kARRAY];

fi >> auxNum;
fi >> auxArray;
```

Once I have read the information from the binary file, I try to assign that values to another variable of the same type, but I get errors and more errors...

```
char arrayResult[kARRAY];

arrayResult = auxArray;
```

What I'm doing wrong? Should I use specific functions due to the fact that I'm reading from a binary file?

Thanks!

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) would be useful. I don't really see why the file is binary and I can't try your code on my computer as I don't have it.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Also, you probably want to do `std::copy(auxArray, auxArray + kARRAY, arrayResult)` or use `std::string` instead.

Comment: The error I'm getting is "invalid assignment matrix".
The file is binary because is with .dat extension.

Comment: Please tell us the contructor parameters you use for the streams. Also, for binary data it is more practical to use std::vector<char> instead of the C-style arrays.

Comment: Do you know what line the error is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int auxNum;
char auxArray[kARRAY];
fi.get(auxArray, kARRAY);
```

Comment: But auxNum is independent of auxArray

Comment: Sorry, it supposed to be kARRAY.

Comment: But reading this way will require null-terminated string to be stored in bineary read